# Multiple GCM push Receiver for same action

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast

I register and receive  GCM push notification in my library project ,The App using my library project have there own implementation of GCM using different Sender ID ,then there could be two different receiver with same action. I tried to send push notifications from server for both sender ID. I couldn't predict the success of push received from both Registration ID

I tried to have only one receiver and redirect to another receiver as seen in http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/23684142-Multiple-Android-Install-Referrers

I suppose one of my registration Id is deleted from GCM server as i receive push from another registration Id.is that true ?,if yes how can i handle this situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting GCM Error: INVALID\_SENDER occasionally in an app that has two GCM BroadcastReceivers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734335/getting-gcm-error-invalid-sender-occasionally-in-an-app-that-has-two-gcm-broadc)

Comment: Hi, ganesh. did you manage to solve it ? I have the same issue, I have an android SDK with GCM which I use in an android application which also uses GCM and I have multiple broadcast receivers with different senderId and I keep getting "NotRegistered" on my server. I'm guessing GCM server deleted my SDK registration Id as well like you mentioned.