# two gcm receiver in android

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging, intentfilter

I have two broadcast receivers and two push services, and  i have registered both receivers in the Manifest File.

**Receiver 1**

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.esri.android.geotrigger.MessageReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.esri.android.geotrigger" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data
                android:path="com.brillio.beaconservice"
                android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Receiver 2**

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.brillio.beaconservice" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

If i comment one receiver and run my application, i am getting push notification properly,

The problem is when both receivers are there is manifest, i am not getting push notification.

Comment: What is the purpose of adding 2 receivers?

Comment: i have two application servers which send two different types of push data

Comment: Then why not you add check on receiver? Two receiver must not work.

Comment: How to differentiate whether the push is from particular application server ?

Comment: Add a key into json data which will contain the server type value. While parsing do your task depend on that value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting GCM Error: INVALID\_SENDER occasionally in an app that has two GCM BroadcastReceivers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734335/getting-gcm-error-invalid-sender-occasionally-in-an-app-that-has-two-gcm-broadc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by enabling and disabling receievers dynamically

using this http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/manifest-receivers.html

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, myReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: Where did you write these code sample? Is it in your mainApplication or Main Activity?

Comment: You can use this code anywhere, in Activity Or Application. It just needs a Context object